# Convert String to JSON Array from Web Request

Tags: java, android, json

i wanted to know how I can convert this string here to an array:

```
[{"title":"test","birth":"20.05"},{"title":"test","birth":"13.05"},{"title":"test","birth":"13.06"},{"title":"test","birth":"23.06"},{"title":"test","birth":"01.12"},{"title":"test","birth":"01.06"}]
```

I already found this here:

```
 JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(readlocationFeed);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("locations");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

But if I try to make the object I always get null. And here:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("locations");
```

I don't know what I should enter as "locations". Should I enter "[]" ?

Thanks really much for help!

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what I should enter as "locations". Should I enter "[]" ?

Nothing `readlocationFeed` is already a `JSONArray`. You just need

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readlocationFeed);
```

without

```
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(readlocationFeed);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("locations");
```

Comment: would be honored if you take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30473371/3287204) ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be the other way around?

```
JSONArray jsnArray = new JSONArray(readlocationFeed);
```

Anyway I suggest you should use GSON for this kind of problem:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClass[] arr = gson.fromJson(str, MyClass[].class);

class MyClass{
    double birth;
    String title;       
}
```